# Find $\sin(t+\pi)$ and $\cos(t+\pi)$ when $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ given

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am learning precalculus and I do not know how to approach when solving this problem:

[image]

Which steps should i take?

Comment: If you want to prove this the long way, consider your sumangle formulas, $\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)+\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$ and $\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)-\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$, then use $\pi$ in place of $\beta$.

Comment: If you want to get straight to the result... notice how sine goes up, then it goes down., and is periodic with period $2\pi$.  You should be able to see visually that $\sin(x+\pi)=-\sin(x)$ and similar for $\cos$.  There are similar results for adding or subtracting $\pi/2$

Comment: Oh!  It's not a multiple-choice problem, it's a problem with four parts....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of (cos(t), sin(t)) as (x,y) coordinates on the unit circle.
I would visualize the point on Quadrant 1, and see what happened next.

$$\begin{matrix}
t → t+\pi & (x,y) → (-x, -y) & \text{Quadrant 3}\cr
t → -t & (x,y) → (x, -y) & \text{Quadrant 4}\cr
t → t+\frac{\pi}{2} & (x,y) → (-y, x) & \text{Quadrant 2}\cr
t → -t+\frac{\pi}{2} & (x,y) → (y,x) & \text{Complementary angles}
\end{matrix}$$

Ignoring the signs, odd $\frac{\pi}{2}$ rotations will swap x and y's.
Then, from the Quadrants, add back the signs.

Answer (score 5):

*Hints:*

For (a), use the fact that $\sin(t+π)=-\sin t$ and $\cos(t+π)=-\cos t$ as well.

For (b), you need to know that $\sin$ is odd and $\cos$ is even. Thus, $\sin(-t)=-\sin t$ and $\cos(-t)=\cos t.$

For (c), use the facts that $\cos(t+π/2)=-\sin t$ and $\sin(t+π/2)=\cos t.$

You should now be able to do (d) by applying the facts I suggested in (c) and (b) above.

Answer (score 1):

use addition/subtraction formulas:
$$\sin(a+b) = \sin(a) \cdot \cos(b)+ \cos (a)\cdot \sin(b)$$

Substitute $-b$ in the formula above, which yields:
\sin(a+(-b)) & = \sin(a-b)\ 
             & = \sin(a) \cdot \cos(-b)+ \cos (a)\cdot \sin(-b)\
             & = \sin(a) \cdot \cos(b) - \cos (a)\cdot \sin(b)

$$\cos(a+b) = \cos(a)\cdot \cos(b) - \sin(a)\cdot \sin(b)$$

Substitute $-b$ in the formula above, which yields:
\cos(a+(-b)) & = \cos(a-b)\
             & = \cos(a) \cdot \cos(-b) - \sin(a) \cdot \sin(-b)\ 
             & = \cos(a) \cdot \cos(b) + \sin(a) \cdot \sin(b)
Now rewrite each angle in terms of $a+b$, in terms of 2 quantities added together $ \\ $
i.e: $-t = 0-t = 0+(-t) $
if you used 0-t, you will use subtraction formula, for $a = 0, b = t \\ $
or you can use addition formula, $0+(-t)$, for $a = 0, b = -t$

Comment: Did you mean rewrite each angle in terms of $a$ and $b$ or by substituting for $a$ and $b$?  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Welcome to MathSE.

Comment: @N.F. Taussig, yes